# Issue for a "two dimentionnal 'add another item' " with FormStateInterface::getTriggeringElement()

Tags: forms, 8

I'm learning drupal 8. I want create a page who contain a 'two dimensionnal' 'add another item' form. My code works well almost, but I have a strange behavior when I add rooms to a house (there is a strange value in my debug logs from the FormStateInterface::getTriggeringElement(), see to the bottom for the code and log)

First : I have two structures, houses and rooms. The user can create some houses and for each house, he can create some rooms :

[image]

When I add some houses, the form works fine :

[image]

When I add some rooms to the last house, the form works fine too :

[image]

But when I add some rooms to any "no-last" house, the form doesn't work fine (in the screenshot, I click one time to the "add room" in the block house '1', the label of the "house 1" became "house 2" (?!) and on click add 5 rooms (?!) :

[image]

Here my code and a strange debug log, I don't explain why I get this value (from the getTriggeringElement() in the room_addMoreSubmit callback and this is the problem I think)

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\projet\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class HouseForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId(){
    return 'custom_rooms_form';
  }

  function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {



    $house_count = $form_state->get('house_count');

    if (is_null($house_count)) {
      $house_count = 1;
      $form_state->set('house_count', $house_count);
    }

    $form['house'] = array(
        //'#tree' => TRUE,
        '#prefix' => '<div id="house-replace">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>'
    );

    for ($house_delta = 0; $house_delta < $house_count; $house_delta++) {
      if (!isset($form['house'][$house_delta])) {

        $room_count[$house_delta] = $form_state->get('room_count_'.$house_delta);

        if (is_null($room_count[$house_delta])) {
          $room_count[$house_delta] = 1;
          $form_state->set('room_count_'.$house_delta, $room_count[$house_delta]);
        }

        dd($room_count, "room_COUNT");

        $form['house'][$house_delta]['room'] = array(
            '#type' => 'fieldset',
            '#title' => t('house : '.$house_delta),
            //'#tree' => TRUE,
            '#prefix' => '<div id="room-replace-'.$house_delta.'">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>'
        );

        for ($room_delta = 0; $room_delta < $room_count[$house_delta]; $room_delta++) {
          if (!isset($form['house'][$house_delta]['room'][$room_delta])) {
            $room = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield'
            );
            $check = array(
                '#type' => 'checkbox'
            );
            $form['house'][$house_delta]['room'][$room_delta] = array(
                '#type' => 'fieldset',
                '#title' => t('room : '.$house_delta.'.'.$room_delta),
            );
            $form['house'][$house_delta]['room'][$room_delta]['text'] = $room;
            $form['house'][$house_delta]['room'][$room_delta]['check'] = $check;
          }
        }

        $form['house'][$house_delta]['room']['add'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name' => 'add',
            '#value' => t('Add room'),
            '#attributes' => array('class' => array('field-add-more-submit'), 'house_delta' => array($house_delta)),
            '#submit' => array(array(get_class($this), 'room_addMoreSubmit')),
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => array($this, 'room_addMoreCallback'),
                'wrapper' => 'room-replace-'.$house_delta,
                'effect' => 'fade',
            ),
        );

      }
    }

    $form['house']['add'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#name' => 'add',
        '#value' => t('Add house'),
        '#attributes' => array('class' => array('field-add-more-submit')),
        '#submit' => array(array(get_class($this), 'house_addMoreSubmit')),
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => array($this, 'house_addMoreCallback'),
            'wrapper' => 'house-replace',
            'effect' => 'fade',
        ),
    );


    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Create'),
    );

    return $form;
  }

  public function room_addMoreSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dd($form_state->getTriggeringElement(), "room : getTriggeringElement()"); // below, the log when I add a room to the house '1' (result see above  with the last screenshot: "the house 1" became "house 2" and one click add 5 rooms)
    $house = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()["#array_parents"][1];
    $c = $form_state->get('room_count_'.$house) + 1;
    $form_state->set('room_count_'.$house, $c);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }

  public function room_addMoreCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $house = $form_state->getTriggeringElement()["#array_parents"][1];
    return $form['house'][$house]['room'];
  }

  public function house_addMoreSubmit(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    dd($form_state->getTriggeringElement()["#array_parents"], "house : getTriggeringElement()"); 
    $c = $form_state->get('house_count') + 1;
    $form_state->set('house_count', $c);
    $form_state->setRebuild(TRUE);
  }

  public function house_addMoreCallback(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['house'];
  }

}
```

The log ('dd' in the room_addMoreSubmit) when I click on the "add room" button in the house "1":

[image]

When I click on the "add room" button in the house number 1, getTriggeringElement return the array parents of the add button. And, as you can see, the parent is "2" not "1" (the house 1)
So when I click on the "add room" button of the house 1, this is the house "2" which is identified and not the house "1".

I don't understand why...Use the getTriggeringElement is not the good way ?

Comment: It is most likely the good old issue with deltas. Drupal still uses numbers(0,1,2,3..) and that in ajaxified forms is pure hell(I've run into it many many times). So in Drupal 8 I always use uuids and if necessary reset keys before saving the values into storage since Drupal expects numeric deltas everywhere.

Comment: uuid and reset...can you provide me a sample example ?=)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ivanjaros/e0ce01dc262c1ffffc3d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know, if this is the error, but i always try to make the names unique when building forms, for example:

```
$form['house'][$house_delta]['room']['add'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#name' => 'add-room-to-house' . $house_delta,
```

Comment: Thanks for answer =) If I set an unique name like you show, how can I get the good unique name from the room_addMoreSubmit callback ?

Comment: Before you get the name "add", and you don't know, which button this is, after that, each button has it's own name and you can indentify the button.

Comment: But I need know which button is triggered from the callback function, thanks that I increment the "room_count_i" variable. Without this variable, I don't know how many room there are in each house

Comment: When each element in your form has it's own #name-attribute, you and most important the form api of drupal should have no problem to identify the correct triggering element.

Comment: Im sorry, I don't understand. If I don't use the room_count var in the callback and I name elements as you say, how the form know (by example) there are 4 rooms in the house 1 ,2 rooms in the house 2 ...? when I rebuild the form

Comment: That was not your question, you asked about the triggering element. To count the elements you can use the $form array.

Comment: I need to know what button is triggered, then, from the callback function I increment the room_count_i ( i => the house id). Then when I rebuild the form, I must know how many field room there are for each house. Thats why I need know wich button "add room" is triggered when I click on a "add" button =)

Comment: I'm stupid x) I don't read correctly your first answer, and set the name as you say debug my issue. Indeed, the unique name was the issue. Thanks you a lot, and sorry again x)