# How to let users remove a specific field or fieldset on a custom form using the form api?

Tags: 8, forms

I followed this Drupal example:
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/examples/blob/8.x-1.x/form_api_example/src/Form/AjaxAddMore.php

I've edited the code a bit to use fieldsets instead of just one field.
This seems to work, though I'm not sure if I did this correctly.

I now have a custom form that allows users to create new fields and remove the last field in the list.

What I need is a remove button next to each field that allows the end-user to choose which field to remove instead of only being able to remove the last field.

I don't know how to get the selected field or fieldset in the submit handler though.

Here's the code I currently have:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\xxx\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class DebtorForm extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'DebtorForm';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // Gather the number of lines in the form already.
    $num_lines = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    // We have to ensure that there is at least one line field.
    if ($num_lines === NULL) {
      $num_field = $form_state->set('num_lines', 1);
      $num_lines = 1;
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('Je onbetaalde factuur'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="invoices-fieldset">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++) {
      // Fieldset line title
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Factuur') . ' ' . ($i + 1),
      ];
      // disputed
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['disputed'] = [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => $this->t('Mijn factuur is'),
        '#options' => array(
          0 => $this->t('Niet betwist'),
          1 => $this->t('Betwist'),
        ),
      ];
      // date
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['date'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Datum factuur'),
      ];
      // amount
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['amount'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Bedrag factuur'),
      ];
      // invoiceId
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['invoiceId'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Factuurnummer'),
      ];
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['invoiceId'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Verwijder'),
        '#submit' => ['::removeCallback'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'invoices-fieldset',
        ],
      ];
    }

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOne'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'invoices-fieldset',
      ],
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;

  }

  /**
   * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
   *
   * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
   */
  public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_field = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    $add_button = $num_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_lines', $add_button);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "remove" button.
   *
   * Removes the corresponding line
   */
  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_field = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    if ($num_field > 1) {
      $remove_button = $num_field - 1;
      $form_state->set('num_lines', $remove_button);
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }


  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to add a #name to the buttons and then use $form_state->getTriggeringElement() in the submit handler? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179168/issue-for-a-two-dimentionnal-add-another-item-with-formstateinterfacegett

Comment: That would help me identify the triggering element, but then how do I get the fieldset the button is in?

Comment: @PascalClaes You might be able to by adding `'#tree' => TRUE,` to your fieldset.

Comment: I can unset the subfield from the $form object, which removes it from the visible form, but it's still present in the $form_state object, which has the values in a protected field, so I cannot unset them there. Using $form_state->unsetValue('names_fieldset') works to remove the entire fieldset, but I only want to remove a single array in names_fieldset, not the entire fieldset, which doesn't seem to work $form_state->unsetValue('names_fieldset[0]') has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After extensive searching and testing I found the following solution:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\form_api_example\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;


class AjaxAddRemoveElements extends FormBase {

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'form_api_example_ajaxaddremoveelements';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    $form['description'] = [
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#markup' => $this->t('This example shows an add-more button and a remove button for each specific element.'),
    ];

    // Get the number of names in the form already.
    $num_lines = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    // We have to ensure that there is at least one name field.
    if ($num_lines === NULL) {
      $form_state->set('num_lines', 1);
      $num_lines = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    }

    // Get a list of fields that were removed
    $removed_fields = $form_state->get('removed_fields');
    // If no fields have been removed yet we use an empty array.
    if ($removed_fields === NULL) {
      $form_state->set('removed_fields', array());
      $removed_fields = $form_state->get('removed_fields');
    }

    $form['#tree'] = TRUE;
    $form['names_fieldset'] = [
      '#type' => 'fieldset',
      '#title' => $this->t('People coming to picnic'),
      '#prefix' => '<div id="names-fieldset-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_lines; $i++) {
      // Check if field was removed
      if (in_array($i, $removed_fields)) {
        // Skip if field was removed and move to the next field
        continue;
      }

      // Create a new fieldset for each person where we can add first and last name
      // Fieldset title
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i] = [
        '#type' => 'fieldset',
        '#title' => $this->t('Person ') . ' ' . ($i + 1),
      ];
      // date
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['firstname'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('First name'),
      ];
      // amount
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['lastname'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('Last name'),
      ];
      $form['names_fieldset'][$i]['actions'] = [
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => $this->t('Remove'),
        '#name' => $i,
        '#submit' => ['::removeCallback'],
        '#ajax' => [
          'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
          'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
        ],
      ];
    }

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions'] = [
      '#type' => 'actions',
    ];

    $form['names_fieldset']['actions']['add_name'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Add one more'),
      '#submit' => ['::addOne'],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::addmoreCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'names-fieldset-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    $form['actions']['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;

  }

  /**
   * Callback for both ajax-enabled buttons.
   *
   * Selects and returns the fieldset with the names in it.
   */
  public function addmoreCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['names_fieldset'];
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "add-one-more" button.
   *
   * Increments the max counter and causes a rebuild.
   */
  public function addOne(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $num_field = $form_state->get('num_lines');
    $add_button = $num_field + 1;
    $form_state->set('num_lines', $add_button);
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }

  /**
   * Submit handler for the "remove" button.
   *
   * Removes the corresponding line
   */
  public function removeCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // We use the name of the remove button to find the element we want to remove
    // Line 72: '#name' => $i,
    $trigger = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    $indexToRemove = $trigger['#name'];

    // Remove the fieldset from $form (the easy way)
    unset($form['names_fieldset'][$indexToRemove]);

    // Remove the fieldset from $form_state (the hard way)
    // First fetch the fieldset, then edit it, then set it again
    // Form API does not allow us to directly edit the field
    $namesFieldset = $form_state->getValue('names_fieldset');
    unset($namesFieldset[$indexToRemove]);
//    $form_state->unsetValue('names_fieldset');
    $form_state->setValue('names_fieldset', $namesFieldset);

    // Keep track of removed fields so we can add new fields at the bottom
    // Without this they would be added where a value was removed
    $removed_fields = $form_state->get('removed_fields');
    $removed_fields[] = $indexToRemove;
    $form_state->set('removed_fields', $removed_fields);

    // Rebuild form_state
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }


  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {

  }

}
```